# C# desktop app with frequent online synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, offline-caching

I'm going to develop a patient management system and its going to be a desktop application built in c# .Net
The problem is that many doctors are going to use it and there cannot be a networking between different rooms as its a government hospital and doctors or doing it on their own, so they cannot afford the networking infrastructure, wht they can do is that they can connect to internet whenever its available on a machine.
Here's what I need. There will be a local database at each machine on which system is installed and it will be updated whenever there's internet availability and user clicks on `update` button.
System will also allow user to update online database. so, both push and pull operations are required to be supported.

---

Now Qustion: Does .Net support this kind of functionality. if yes then any specific api and if no, what options do I have.

Comment: c# supports it, other option you have is to build it as a web application.

Comment: Did you cehck legal? This smells like you are in a world of pain. MEdical information over the internet - that is illegal in most jurisdictions without a LOT of programming.

Comment: Look into the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx). However, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004%28v=vs.90%29.aspx is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be transmitting patient records over the Internet then you are going to have to think very carefully about the legality of doing so. This will almost certainly involve ensuring that the patient records are stored and transmitted encrypted, that the server upon which they are stored is carefully configured and maintained with essential security updates and that the doctors' PCs accessing this data are validated as being permitted to do so (authenticated as being legitimate and authorised as having permission to access the particular records).

Getting any of this wrong could lead to confidential patient data being leaked which could land your surgery (and potentially yourself) liable to lawsuits. You may even be putting yourself at risk of criminal charges if you are found negligent. (IANAL, you will need to do your own due diligence.)

Personally I would suggest doing everything you can to have a LAN put in place. This should remove the more sensitive of these legal concerns as you will no longer be interfacing with a public network. Networking is not expensive or hard, you might even be able to get the budget to put it in place yourself if you explain the situation and provide details of its cost.

If you have a multitude of doctors PCs, each updating their own local caches of data and then, periodically, updating a centralised store then sooner or later you will find that you will end up with data conflicts. A naive system will simply overwrite the old data with the most recently pushed change, losing any earlier independent changes. As I am guessing you do not want data loss then you will need to pick a strategy to avoid this. This could involve record locking or some form of conflict resolution. Have a look at the [concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_access) Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

> Does c# support this kind of functionality.

Yes, it is called programming. C# is a language (as per langauge specifications). It supports everything someone programs.

> if yes then any specific api and if no, what options do I have

Not in C#, no. C# has no API at all - not even an API to write a line on a console (Console.WriteLine is an API of the .NET framework, not of the C# application).

Microsoft has a SYNC FRAMEWORK that you can use, if you sue SQL Server or write your own providers for that. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx for a start on this framework.